# How did I obtain 100 Premier Balls?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I played Pokemon X last year, and stopped playing after a while. Beat e4, bred some nice Pokemon, but never had the courage to play online and get my ass whipped. Therefor I didn't touch the game for some months. After beating the e4 in ORAS, I decided that I want to make a [living Pokedex](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Living_Pok%C3%A9dex), with the aid of Pokebank. I booted Pokemon X and before I went to the Friend Safari's to catch Pokemon I hadn't caught yet, I checked my Pokeballs. Exactly as I suspected, I had quite some duskballs and quickballs left, but also ~100 Premier balls. I don't remember buying 100 times 10 balls to obtain the Premier balls (and I don't have that many balls left). Was there some sort of event that you obtained those balls? It is plausible from the description:

> A somewhat rare Poké Ball that was made as a commemorative item used to celebrate an event of some sort.

So I finished the game, but didn't participate in any events in the last ~8 months for Pokemon X, except for a Diancie and ORAS demo. So, **how did I obtain 100 Premier Balls?**

Comment: Did you forget you can buy them from the Pokeball store in Lumiose?

Comment: I think I forgot that. I thought the only source of Premier balls was when you bought >10 balls at the same time.

Comment: Nah, in Lumiose they made it a lot easier lol. :-)

Comment: Hmm. I always liked the color of Premier balls. And money was never a problem (especially with the O-Powers). Good thing I catched all FS Pokemon so far with those balls :)

Comment: Haha awesome! Yeah I prefer the design myself as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its possible you bought them from the Lumiose City Pokeball store. Whilst it is still possible to get them as a bonus from buying >10 balls at once, it is also possible to purchase them outright.

Further: a lot of people use this strategy to raise their style rating, as buying them one-by-one raises your style by a small amount

Comment: It was indeed that style!! You needed that for the [Hatching O-Power](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67617233). Totally forgot about that, thanks!